# Understanding the IOexceptin()

Tags: java, exception

This is an assignment for class and I'm still learning to understand some exceptions. There is an error within the IOexception and I'm not sure what to do about it. I don't think I understand what it is or if I'm in the right direction. Any suggestions? Can anyone explain this exception for me? - I did try google and the use of my class book but I'm still having trouble understanding and applying exceptions.

```java
try {
    BasicFileAttributes someAttr = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    System.out.println("File last modified date and time: " + someAttr.lastModifiedTime());
    System.out.println("File Size: " + someAttr.size());
}
catch(IOexception) {
    System.out.println("IO Exception");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your catch(IOexception) you have to name the IOexception something.... 
since IOexception is an object you have to give it a name.
i.e. IOexception e.
It's the same as if you were trying to pass an integer parameter to a function
functionname(int a)

Answer (score 2):

I'd fix your catch statement to something like this

```
}(catch IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();//this will help you understand what's going on with the exception
}
```

If you look at the stack trace for the exception, it will say what the root cause of the exception is and can help you fix it. The stack trace will include method, class and line number where the exception is being thrown.

Also, for future reference, sometimes the silly error messages or error messages that say things like "Exception" are silly at the time, but it will come and bite you in the rear when it comes time to actually figure out what really broke in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```java
try {....}
catch(IOexception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

To get more info about the error, you can also use:

```java
System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace());
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing the actual error message would be helpful to you:

```
catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println (ex.toString());
}
```